# Kivy (Python) : unable to use variables of class from one file to other

Tags: python, kivy

mainfile: Using kivy filechooser, I have selected one csv file, grab the data and converted into lists.(names and age)
subfile:I want to plot graph using names(x axis) and age(y axis) defined in mainfile.

mainfile.py:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder

import os
import csv

Builder.load_file('design2.kv')
class MyWidget(BoxLayout):
    def open(self, path, filename):
        with open(os.path.join(path, filename[0])) as f:
            csv_data = csv.reader(f)
            datalines = list(csv_data)
            names = [i[0] for i in datalines]
            age = [i[1] for i in datalines]
            print(names)
            print(age)
class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyWidget()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

design2.kv:

```
<MyWidget>:
    id: my_widget
    FileChooserListView:
        id: filechooser
        filters: ['*.csv']
        on_selection: my_widget.open(filechooser.path, filechooser.selection)
```

subfile:

```
from mainfile import*
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.plot(names,age)
plt.show()
```

Im unable to create graph because in subfile names and age are showing undefined.

**Please help me out**

Answer (score 0):

Your `names` and `ages` are only defined as local variables within the scope of the `open()` method of `MyWidget`. If you want to expose them to be available for use outside the `open()` method, they must be defined at the global level. So, you can modify your `mainfile.py` to do that:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder

import os
import csv

# define names and ages to make them available for import
names = []
age = []

Builder.load_file('design2.kv')
class MyWidget(BoxLayout):
    def open(self, path, filename):
        global names, age
        with open(os.path.join(path, filename[0])) as f:
            csv_data = csv.reader(f)
            datalines = list(csv_data)
            names = [i[0] for i in datalines]
            age = [i[1] for i in datalines]
            print(names)
            print(age)
class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyWidget()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Also, you need to modify `subfile` slightly:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import mainfile
mainfile.MyWidget().open('a', 'b')  # set the values of names and age
print(mainfile.names, mainfile.age)
plt.plot(mainfile.names,mainfile.age)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you!!.using this method i can import names and age. but it wil be empty list. unable to get names and age data from class

Comment: Oops, forgot a `global` statement. I have updated my answer.

Comment: still it is empty list outside the class.

Comment: Before printing the values of `names` and `age` in your `subfile`, you must execute the `open()` method of `MyWidget`, in order to get the values set to something other than `[]`.

Comment: I have also edited my answer to show the changes needed in `subfile`.

Comment: open() method has path and filename as its parameters. there i cant give names and age. moreover requirement is user can choose any csv file and data may varies. so names and age should be csv data. not user data.

Comment: its simple. using kivy user will select one file, grab the data and converted into graphs. but graphing should be in other file. we often change the selection of column, row, styling etc.